# Remove an object from an array if there are duplicate values. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the array `[{fruit1:"apple"},{fruit2:"banana"},{fruit3:"apple"}]` how would I remove an element that had a duplicate value. In this example, I would only want to keep one of the key-value pairs that have "apple", removing that element from an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). For each object, extract the key/value pair with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Unless a Map's key (`apple` for example) already exists, use the value as the key of a new Map entry, and the original key as the value. Then you can convert it back to an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), and switch the keys and the values:

```js
const data = [{fruit1:"apple"},{fruit2:"banana"},{fruit3:"apple"}];

const result = Array.from(
  data.reduce((m, o) => {
    const [k, v] = Object.entries(o)[0];

    return m.has(v) ? m : m.set(v, k);
  }, new Map()),
  ([k, v]) => ({ [v]: k })
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer It could be that OP is dealing with user input, and is removing duplicates as it's input, so the data will never have more than one duplicate at a time.